# Why can't you get one-off stickers/vinyls printed?

Tags: print-production, vinyl

I am trying to find sites that can create one(or two)-off stickers/vinyls that are transparent. From what I am getting is that it may not be profitable enough to make it worth the company's time but if they did one-off batches (multiple client) would it not be possible to be worthwhile?

I was looking at http://www.stickeryou.com/ but the best I can do for transparent ones is $20 a page/unique sticker (which comes out to 8 copies of one sticker in my case). All I'm hoping for is to get two different stickers printed for some hobby projects but the cost is significant compared to the rest of the project and if I need more one-offs it just doesn't seem practical.

Did I hit a gap where it's not practical for me at one end and not practical for the business at the other?

Am I going the wrong route? Is there a better alternative for putting graphics on hobby projects? I am creating/fixing a few guitar pedals and would like to be able to put some basic graphics and text on the face of them

PS: If you know where I can get one-offs you can post those in the comments below my question

Note: Added some more context to what I am doing

Comment: Someone on [fiverr](http://www.fiverr.com/search/gigs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search_in=everywhere&query=vinyl&page=1&layout=auto) might be able to fulfill your need

Comment: @JohnB That fiverr thing is neat and might help me with the who and where of my question

Comment: They make transparent sticker paper for inkjet printers. Perhaps that's an option? Of course they are *necessarily* weatherproof then.

Comment: @Scott Hi, I had thought of that before but I am unsure if the quality would be as good and if the cost of buying an inkjet specifically for this would be worthwhile. Are you familiar with any writeups on this process?

Comment: In case anyone is curious, I was able to get what I wanted through here: https://www.fiverr.com/stickerdonkey/make-stickers-of-your-logo-on-transparent-vinyl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to find sites that can create one(or two)-off
>   stickers/vinyls that are transparent. From what I am getting is that
>   it may not be profitable enough to make it worth the company's time
>   but if they did one-off batches (multiple client) would it not be
>   possible to be worthwhile?

Something that you have to understand when it comes to production related services  there are factors companies (like digital printing) have to put in play to be profitable.  I will use your issue as an example:

Say you have two stickers that come to be a total length of 12" in material.  It costs you another 6" material to feed it through the printer and another 6" to feed it through lamination (if you are going to get it) which is considered as material waste because some machines require X amount of material to be able to be fed and printed on.  The setup time is the same, you have to enter the design you provided, check to make sure its a correct vector, load the material, align the material, cut the material, etc. etc., and hit the print button.  After printing, if they have a plotter, they will run it through the plotter and it will cutout what you needed..

Now you order 24" in material and my material waste is deleted and my production setup and print times dont change..  If you order 144" of material what are the factors that only change?  Material, print time..  So that is why its better to order in bulk and small orders are usually not allowed or there is a min. order charge when placing orders because it will take the same amount of time to print 12" of stickers VS 24" of stickers (plus a little increased in print and plot times)..  If you print 12" of stickers you are probably going to break even which means you will be out of business soon..

> Am I going the wrong route? Is there a better alternative for putting
>   graphics on hobby projects?

I think maybe but since you haven't posted an example of why you need to go transparent I will just explain the differences.  Transparent vinyl is a lot more expensive than simply white vinyl that can be printed on.  I would ask why do you need it to be transparent.  Do you need to actually see through it?  If no, then look into die cut stickers and we do have a question on it:  "[What term is used to refer to cut vinyl stickers?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30894/what-term-is-used-to-refer-to-cut-vinyl-stickers)".

> PS: If you know where I can get one-offs you can post those in the
>   comments below my question

I think you may be looking in the wrong areas and I say that because searching online for one-offs you simply wont find it because they are looking for large, profitable, runs.  Your best option would be to scout locally and use services like Craigslist, Facebook, local user groups, and you could even go to meetup and look for a local printers group where someone is doing this has a home hobby or starting out.  I would also consider going into a local sign show and asking for a sheet to printed of your design and see if they will cut costs and you can just peel them off yourself like a very large sticker book.

Comment: I will update my question with more context. Basically I am creating/fixing a few guitar pedals and would like to be able to put some basic graphics and text on the face of them

Answer (score 0):

Try different methods of transfer - I saw one method by using a lazer printer with highest quality ink down on some thin paper stock, but you print in reverse, then you use a varnish or acetone of some sort with transfer face down.[try this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Solvent-Transfers/) The liquid sends the paper transparent but keeps the lazer ink intact - not sure if you remove the paper or it dissolves the ink - Just found by GOOGLING. This was done on up-cycled glasses and old water bottles for sale at a market stall. or try your hand at stencils/airbrushing.